# Recyclerview's item is selecting duplicate position and changing textcolor

Tags: android

if I select one item from list another item is also getting selected.
For example, I selected the first item then the first item's color is changing but along with this 13 other items color's are also changing. I am sharing the code files along with this post. Please review it.

Can someone please help me?

```
public class ArealistAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ArealistAdapter.Pendingholder> {
    Context context;
    List<Area> pendingModels;
    RecycleviewOnitemclick recycleviewOnitemclick;

    public ArealistAdapter(Context context, List<Area> pendingModels, RecycleviewOnitemclick recycleviewOnitemclick) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pendingModels = pendingModels;
        this.recycleviewOnitemclick = recycleviewOnitemclick;
    }

    class Pendingholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView textView4;

        public Pendingholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView4=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbCheck);

        }


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArealistAdapter.Pendingholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search,parent,false);




        return new Pendingholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArealistAdapter.Pendingholder holder, int position) {
Area pendingModel=pendingModels.get(position);
holder.textView4.setText(pendingModel.getArea());
holder.textView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.textView4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
});

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pendingModels.size();
    }


    public  interface RecycleviewOnitemclick{
        void clickitem();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store selected positions state in a data structure (selectedMap) like Map or SpareArray, and in onBindViewHolder function, just simply check whether item was selected or not:

```
  private Map<Int,Boolean> selectedMap = new HashMap();
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArealistAdapter.Pendingholder holder, int position) {
              boolean isPositionSelected = selectedMap.get(position);
              if(isPositionSelected  ==null || isPositionSelected  == false){
                 holder.textView4.setTextColor(defaultColor);
             }else{
                holder.textView4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
             }
    }
```

And inside onClick function, just update the selected state of that position:

```
holder.textView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isPositionSelected = selectedMap.get(getAdapterPosition());
           if(isPositionSelected  ==null || isPositionSelected  == false){
             selectedMap.set(getAdapterPosition(),true);
          }else{
            selectedMap.set(getAdapterPosition(),false);
          }
        }
    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try not to put any thing other than setting text or so in your onBindViewHolder as this method is call repeatedly.

To implement a click listener, I would suggest adding it to the view holder class (PendingHolder) just after findViewById  as this is called less often.

You can create a method such as :

```
Private void onClickTxt(Textview tv) {
    tv.setOnClickListener..........
}
```

This method should be called from your view holder class. Not the onBindView.

Feel free to add a comment.

Happy coding.

PS if my answer helped you, a ☑ would be nice

Answer (score 0):

**This is happening because recyclerview works on the basic logic of recycling the views**. so if you set colour of a view at position 1 as blue but others are black, while recycling it can cause some issues.

Solution:
I personally add a is_selected boolean field in the model class of original array and set it as false by default. when it is selected, you can set the color of view as you want programmatically.

So, in your case:

1. **Add is_selected** in Area class.
2. in **onBindViewHolder()** class, if you get the is_selected as current position as true, you can set it as selected color or else the default color
3. in **onClick** of textview, set the is_selected as true/false for current position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the text color is already green or not. If its not green only then change its color, Otherwise keep it as it is. It means you need to add an else condition with the if.